# Running Gazebo and ROS on a remote instance

Tags: ros, gazebo, gazebo-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First off, let me say that I know that similar questions have been asked before, but I have been unable to find any answers that actually solve my problem.

I am trying to run Gazebo and the associated gazebo_ros package on a headless OpenStack instance, and using the `gzweb` software to access it through a browser. I do not need `gzclient` to be running on this instance at all. When I run the following command:

```
roslaunch gazebo_ros empty_world.launch
```

it gives me the following error:

> Error [RenderEngine.cc:680] Unable to
> create glx visual

> Warning [RenderEngine.cc:88] Unable to create
> X window. Rendering will be disabled

Other similar questions (such as [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/35013/running-gazebo-headless-in-fuerte-over-ssh/) and [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/9324/run-gazebo-remotely/)) suggest using `DISPLAY=:0`, but when I add this into the command as follows:

```
DISPLAY=:0 roslaunch gazebo_ros empty_world.launch
```

it gives me a different error:

> Error [RenderEngine.cc:665] Can't open
> display: :0

> Warning [RenderEngine.cc:88] Unable to create
> X window. Rendering will be disabled

I have also tried setting

```
<arg name="gui" default="false"/> 
<arg name="headless" default="true"/>
```

in the empty_world.launch file, but no luck. I'm pulling my hair out here trying to get this thing working. Any advice would be hugely appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207520/running-gazebo-and-ros-on-a-remote-instance/) by [Jordan9](https://answers.ros.org/users/22059/jordan9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2015-04-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not an expert on Gazebo, or openstack, but I have seen some similar stuff before. Perhaps the X11 configuration is not set up properly. You are running openstack headless. Does it have an X window server installed/properly configured? Ultimately that is what will enable you to access the GUI over the network.

---

Originally posted by [aak2166](https://answers.ros.org/users/21299/aak2166/) with karma: 593 on 2015-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jordan9](https://answers.ros.org/users/22059/jordan9/) on 2015-04-23**:
Yeah, I think it's an X11 server problem, not a Gazebo problem. Will move to a more appropriate question forum.